# How do I Update an array before the Dom renders in React

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a practice project where I have a dummy JSON containing products, I want to display it as a drop-down..  but as soon as I select an element it runs into an infinite rending loop...

//This is the Reducer

```
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/action";
    import { updateObject } from "../../shared/utility";
 
const initialState = {
  product: [],
};
 
const getProduct = (state, action) => {
  const updatedProduct = {
    product: action.product,
  };
  console.log(updatedProduct);
  return updateObject(state, updatedProduct);
};
 
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT:
      return getProduct(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }`enter code here`
};
 
export default reducer;
```

//This is the action File

```
import * as actionTypes from "./action";
 
import TrialData from "../../data/trial.json";

 
export const getProduct = (updatedProductList) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT,
    product: updatedProductList,
  };
};
 
export const initProduct = () => {
  let display, displayName, jsonObject, uniqueSet, filteredProducts;
  const productList = [];
  TrialData.forEach((el) => {
    display = el.appID;
    displayName = display.slice(4);
    productList.push({
      value: el.appID,
      displayValue: displayName,
    });
  });
 
  jsonObject = productList.map(JSON.stringify);
 
  uniqueSet = new Set(jsonObject);
  filteredProducts = Array.from(uniqueSet).map(JSON.parse);
 
  return (dispatch) => dispatch(getProduct(filteredProducts));
};
```

//This is the header from where i am dispatching the action

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
 
import * as actions from "../../store/actions/index";
import Input from "../../Components/UI/Input/input";
import classes from "./header.css";
import { updateObject } from "../../shared/utility";
 
const header = (props) => {
  console.log("rendering header");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
 
  const onInitProduct = useCallback(() => dispatch(actions.initProduct()), [
    dispatch,
  ]);
 
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   onInitProduct();
  // }, [onInitProduct]);
  //Even i tried this but this gives me empty arrays
 
  onInitProduct()
 
  let products = useSelector((state) => state.headerFilter.product);
 
  console.log(products);
 
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    product: {
      elementType: "select",
      elementConfig: {
        options: products,
      },
      value: "",
      displayTitle: "Select Product",
      containerClass: classes.header__products,
      classElement: classes.products,
    },
    order: {
      elementType: "select",
      elementConfig: {
        options: [
          { value: "newest first", displayValue: "Newest First" },
          { value: "oldest first", displayValue: "Oldest First" },
        ],
      },
      value: "",
      displayTitle: "Sorting",
      containerClass: classes.sorting,
      classElement: classes.filter_name,
    },
    translation: {
      elementType: "select",
      elementConfig: {
        options: [
          { value: "english", displayValue: "English" },
          { value: "hindi", displayValue: "Hindi" },
        ],
      },
      value: "",
      displayTitle: "Translation",
      containerClass: classes.translation,
      classElement: classes.filter_name,
    },
  });
  const selectElementArray = [];
  for (let key in options) {
    selectElementArray.push({
      id: key,
      config: options[key],
    });
  }
 
  const inputChangedHandler = (event, inputIdentifier) => {
    const updatedFormElement = updateObject(options[inputIdentifier], {
      value: event.target.value,
    });
 
    console.log(updatedFormElement);
    const updatedOptions = updateObject(options, {
      [inputIdentifier]: updatedFormElement,
    });
 
    console.log("updating object", updatedFormElement);
    console.log("re..rednering...", updatedOptions);
    setOptions(updatedOptions);
 
    console.log("afterRendering", options);
  };
 
  let form = selectElementArray.map((selectElement) => {
    return (
      <Input
        key={selectElement.id}
        elementType={selectElement.config.elementType}
        elementConfig={selectElement.config.elementConfig}
        value={selectElement.config.value}
        displayTitle={selectElement.config.displayTitle}
        containerClass={selectElement.config.containerClass}
        classElement={selectElement.config.classElement}
        changed={(event) => inputChangedHandler(event, selectElement.id)}
      />
    );
  });
 
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <header className={classes.header}>
        {form.map((el) => {
          if (el.key === "product") {
            return el;
          }
        })}
 
        <div className={classes.header__filter}>
          {form.map((element) => {
            if (element.key !== "product") {
              return element;
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </header>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
 
export default header;
```

//And this is Input component

```
import React from "react";

import Icon from "../Icons/icon";
import classes from "./input.css";

const input = (props) => {
  let inputElement = null;
  switch (props.elementType) {
    case "input":
      inputElement = (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Icon iconName={props.iconName} />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search"
            value={props.value}
            onChange={props.changed}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
      break;
    case "select":
      inputElement = (
        <div className={props.containerClass}>
          <label htmlFor="products" className={classes.filter_title}>{props.displayTitle}</label>
          <select
            className={props.classElement}
            value={props.value}
            onChange={props.changed}
          >
            {props.elementConfig.options.map((option) => (
              <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                {option.displayValue}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      );
      break;
    default:
      null;
  }

  return inputElement;
};

export default input;
```

Dummy product that i am recieveing is in a form of array

```
[{value: "com.myntra", displayValue: "myntra"},
 {value: "com.flipkart", displayValue: "flipkart"},
 {value: "com.google", displayValue: "google"},`enter code here`
{value: "com.amazon", displayValue: "amazon"}]
```

Edit:
[This is the link to Sandbox..](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-faraday-wupyp?file=/index.js)

[And this is the redux Devtool for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd)

Comment: Could you share a sandbox with your code?

Comment: Yes.. I have uploaded the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I got a solution from one friend.. the product is updated in the code, but the options was not updated..just had to place this in the header file

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setOptions(prevOptions => {
      return ({
        ...prevOptions,
        product: {
          ...prevOptions.product,
          elementConfig: {
            options: products
          }
        }
      })

    })
  }, [products])
```